# Android. Implementing of splash screen with animations

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, splash-screen, android-theme

I know that there are 2 common methods of implementing splash screens:

1. Using activity and Timers
2. Using a Launcher Theme

Using a Launcher theme is the preferred way because I need splash while cold start.

But suppose I need to implement a splash screen with animated logo, text and background.

Is it possible using the Launcher Theme to create animated splash screen or animations is quite not possible in this method and I will have to create separate activity for my splash screen.

Please help me)

Comment: https://medium.com/android-news/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565 : This article has detailed a few things about splash screen best practices. This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Android's SplashScreenApi to launch your app.
This includes an into-app motion at launch, a splash screen showing your app icon, and a transition to your app itself. This provides a seamless transition into our app -
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen